# Difference between semicolon and `let _ = ... in` in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

On [this site](https://baturin.org/docs/ocaml-faq/) it says a semicolon is semantically the same as `let _ = ... in`, however that isn't the case in the following code. This code prints `None` and `End`:

```ml
let m = None

let () =
  let () = match m with
    | None -> print_endline "None"
    | Some file -> print_endline "Some"
  in
  print_endline "End";
```

However this code only prints `None`.

```ml
let m = None

let () =
  match m with
    | None -> print_endline "None"
    | Some file -> print_endline "Some"
  ;
  print_endline "End";
```

Why? What's the difference between a semicolon and `let in`?

Comment: *Beware* that `;` has NOT the same meaning as `;;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OCaml is not white-space sensitive. Your second example reads as

```ml
let m = None

let () =
  match m with
    | None -> print_endline "None"
    | Some file -> print_endline "Some"; print_endline "End"
```

which only prints `End` in the `Some file` case.

In other words, if you translate your first example

```ml
let () =
  let () = match m with
    | None -> print_endline "None"
    | Some file -> print_endline "Some"
  in
  print_endline "End"
```

to use `;`, you need to parenthese it:

```
let () =
  (match m with
    | None -> print_endline "None"
    | Some file -> print_endline "Some"
   );
  print_endline "End"
```

to delimit the expression that was enclosed in the  `let ... in`  pair.

Answer (score 1):

Clarification on something you've shown.

```
let _ = print_endline "hello" in
print_endline "world"
```

Is not *quite* equivalent to:

```
print_endline "hello";
print_endline "world"
```

The `_` pattern used in the former will match *anything*.  Let's consider a slightly different contrived example:

```
# let _ = 42 in
  print_endline "hello world";;
hello world
- : unit = ()
# 42; print_endline "hello world";;
Warning 10 [non-unit-statement]: this expression should have type unit.
hello world
- : unit = ()
```

This time in the latter, the compiler warns us that `42` does not evaluate to `unit`. This is a useful warning to avoid potential errors.  As octachron's code does, this is not an issue if we bind to `()` rather than `_`. We are explicitly saying the value cannot be *anything* but rather must evaluate to `unit`.

```
# let () = 42 in
  print_endline "hello world";;
Error: This pattern matches values of type unit
       but a pattern was expected which matches values of type int
```

Still not quite the same. In this case we get an immediate compiler error rather than a warning, but at least the issue is not completely ignored.